# Istio - SPIFFE Trust Federation

Tags: istio

In the following Istio documentation page - https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/deployment-models/#trust-between-meshes - it mentions using SPIFFE federation to import a trust bundle to a mesh.

I can't seem to find any other documentation that states how to do this, or if it is even possible. Does anyone have any insight as to how to federate either two Istio clusters using SPIFFE Federation, or an Istio cluster and a different SPIFFE endpoint such as SPIRE?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Istio do you have ?
I think you can find helpful resources [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx_NnvbsCP4).

Comment: @matt_j - Latest version of Istio would be fine. I actually saw the code that that Demo you linked uses, and I believe it's still a WIP, and they mention having to edit Istio Pilot to get it working. I was more curious in official support / documentation. Seems odd they mention that type of federation in their docs, but there doesn't appear to be any first-party support for it.